# Validating optional form input in Spring

Tags: spring, validation

Starting from this **[example](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)**, I'm developing my own class in order to validate form inputs with **Spring**.

I defined an option field `<input id="middleName" name="middleName" th:field="*{middleName}" />`, and now I'd like to check its value as follows:

```
if middleName is not blank
   then if ((middleName has length < 3) && (middleName has length > 10) && (compare middleName value to regEx))
       then return error
else
    then return success
```

However, I'd like to perform a control only if `middleName` is specified.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of Validator interface and provide your own custom logic to validate the form. You can hook up the implementation of this interface in spring and use @validated annotation to perform the validation.

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation)